# Retrieving databases and their collections in Node JS with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to get all the Mongo databases I have on MongoDB Compass along with their collections to get an object like :

```
{
db_name1:{
collection_name1,
collection_name2,
},
db_name2:{
collection_name1,
collection_name2,
collection_name3,
}
}
```

Is there a simple way to find all databases and their collections ? Or do I have to retrieve the DB names and then, by names search for their collections ?

Thanks in advance.